# Two different format when using same java classes in java application and android application

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

I used same methods to generate date and time in java application and an android application , but i got surprised to see that the output produced by the same function is different, i am amused why this happen when we use the methods in two different platforms, can anybody please explain.

Here is the output

```
Java application output ---Fri Jul 18 12:51:17 IST 2014
Android application output----Thu Jul 17 18:46:05 GMT+05:30 2014
```

Here is the code which returns date [same code used for same applications]

```
private Date offsetTimeZone(Date date, String fromTZ, String toTZ) {

        // Construct FROM and TO TimeZone instances
        TimeZone fromTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTZ);
        TimeZone toTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(toTZ);
        System.out.println("timezone:" + fromTimeZone);
        // Get a Calendar instance using the default time zone and locale.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set the calendar's time with the given date
        calendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone);
        calendar.setTime(date);

        System.out.println("Input: " + calendar.getTime() + " in "
                + fromTimeZone.getDisplayName());



        // UTC to TO TimeZone
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, toTimeZone.getRawOffset());

        if (toTimeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, toTimeZone.getDSTSavings());
        }

        return calendar.getTime();

    }
```

Calling the method from android application

```
 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                            Locale.ENGLISH).parse(_data.get(position).get_date());
                    date2 = offsetTimeZone(date, "UTC", timezoneID);
```

Calling the method from java application

```
try {
            String timezoneID = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
            System.out.println("idd:" + timezoneID);
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2014-07-18 07:21:17");
            Date date2 = offsetTimeZone(date, "UTC", timezoneID);
            System.out.println("output" + date2.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like different time zones. What is the value of timezoneID in each case?

Comment: both returns Asia/Calcutta time zone

Comment: Have you tried replacing _data.get(position).get_date() with "2014-07-18 07:21:17" in the android code? i.e. Is get_date() returning "2014-07-18 07:21:17"?

Comment: yes ,I have tried that but still the same answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a complete answer but to help narrow it down...

This documents exactly what format you should expect:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29

Both Android and regular Java use the same format for their output.

For some reason zzz in one example is being displayed as GMT+05:30 and in the other it is being displayed as IST.

It is possible that the timezone naming database does not know the name of IST in one case and has displayed the timezone offset instead. The Javadoc for regular Java though says *"If time zone information is not available, then zzz is empty - that is, it consists of no characters at all."* which suggests otherwise.